# Getting Google's datastore Key value with Go

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore

I have a struct:

```
type struct Foo {
    Id ??
    Name string
}
```

I get a list of Foos doing, where "c" is a NewContext():

```
    q := datastore.NewQuery("Drug")
    var foos []Foo
    _, err := q.GetAll(c, &foos)
```

The Id is not populated, but the Name is.
I'm trying to figure out how to get the Id to populate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [GetAll](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Query.GetAll) function returns a slice of the keys:

```
keys, err := q.GetAll(c, &foos)
```

The key for foos[i] is keys[i].

Use a loop to store the id in the entity if that's what you need:

```
for i := range keys {
   foos[i].ID = keys[i].IntID() // or .StringID()
}
```